# How do I print the number of entries assigned to a category?

Tags: templating

Okay, all I want to do is list all categories AND the # of entries associated with each category.

```
{% set numofEntries = craft.entries.section('posts').relatedTo(category).total() %}

<p class="tags">
    {% for categoryName in craft.categories.group('markets') %}
        <a href="{{ categoryName.url }}">{{ categoryName.title }}-{{numofEntries}}</a>
    {% endfor %}
</p>
```

No error is thrown (and I am in dev mode), but the number that appears (49) is the same for all categories (and doesn't even equal the number of total entries).

A few things...

- market group = markets ...
- the category field handler = marketName

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to query for the number of entries *inside* the for loop.

```
{% for categoryName in craft.categories.group('markets') %}
    {% set numofEntries = craft.entries.section('posts').relatedTo(categoryName).total() %}

    <a href="{{ categoryName.url }}">{{ categoryName.title }}-{{numofEntries}}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to display the total number of entries related to *each* category, you'll need to put the `{% set numofEntries ... %}` statement inside your `for` loop. You'll also need to change the `relatedTo(category)` part to `relatedTo(categoryName)` (or change the `categoryName` to `category`, which would probably be more appropriate).

Something like this should work:

```
{% set numofEntries = craft.entries.section('posts').relatedTo(category).total() %}

<p class="tags">
    {% set categories = craft.categories.group('markets') %}
    {% for category in categories %}
        {% set numofEntries = craft.entries.section('posts').limit(null).relatedTo({
            targetElement: category,
            field: marketName
        }).total() %}
        <a href="{{ category.url }}">{{ category.title }}-{{numofEntries}}</a>
    {% endfor %}
</p>
```

Note: You don't actually need to feed the `targetElement` and `field` attributes to the `relatedTo()` parameter – simply `relatedTo(category)` will usually work just fine – but it's supposedly more performant to be as specific as possible about the relation you're looking for – in this case; any entries that have the `category` selected (i.e. the `targetElement`) in the Categories field `marketName`.